# /usr/bin/python3.3 not found from brp-scl-python-bytecompile during mock build

Tags: python, centos, rpm

I'm trying to build python33-python-virtualenv under CentOS6. I'm currently just trying to rebuild the current version as present in: https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/rhscl/python33/epel-6-x86_64/python33-python-virtualenv-1.10.1-1.el6.src.rpm

I'm getting an error: `/usr/lib/rpm/brp-scl-python-bytecompile: line 47: /usr/bin/python3.3: No such file or directory`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

NB: I'm doing this in a mock environment, with scl defined to python33.

Comment: This is an outstanding first question! The title was a little more generic than it needed to be (in general, a title should be specific enough that it strikes the eye only of people having the same problem), but... welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a 'python33-build' package installed in mock every time you build a sub-package of the python33 collection. You need to modify the mock config as follows:

replace: `config_opts['chroot_setup_cmd'] = 'install @buildsys-build'`

with: `config_opts['chroot_setup_cmd'] = 'install @build scl-utils-build python33-build'`

Generally, there need to be a '-build' package installed every time you build a sub-package for that collection. The '-build' package is built from the meta package source. In this specific case it would come from python33 source:
https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/rhscl/python33-el7/build/27227/